# Prove that $n^2 < n \cdot (n - 1) \cdot (n -2) $

Tags: calculus

How to prove or disprove that: $$ n^2 < n \cdot (n - 1) \cdot (n -2)   $$ for every $n > 0$

Comment: Please add your effort to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This holds only for $n \geq 4$. Since $n>0$, dividing both sides by $n$ preserves the inequality, so it reads

$n<n^2 + 2 - 3n \Longleftrightarrow 0<n^2 - 4n + 2 \Longleftrightarrow 0 < (n-2)^2 -  2$.

The statement is thus untrue.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you mean that $n$ is a natural number. Then, your claim is not true.

Here is how to disprove this. Find a counterexample. Take $n=1$. If your question was true, then $1<0$. A contradiction! Similarly, it does not hold for $n=2$, as $4>0$. Or $n=3$ either, since $9>6$.